# R. Compare several columns and categories (rows) with a specific column, iteratively

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have a big data.frame in R whose oversimplified version looks like this:

```
Category    A   B   C   D   Total 
flower      5   5   3   6   19 
car         2   2   2   2   8 
tree        7   8   1   7   23 
ball        1   4   5   2   12
```

I would like to compare column "Total" with A, B, C and D (the real file has >100 columns and >10 Categories) in an iterative way by performing some operations using dplyr. At the end I would like to rbind the output of each iteration.
For instance, let's consider a simple operation for "Total" vs "A", a subtraction which would result in column "Y". Then multiply every row of "Y" by the sum along column "A", resulting in column "X" (In reality I want to perform more and more complex operations). By doing the same for columns B, C and D, I would get a data.frame that could look like this:

```
Column  Category Count  Y    X 
A       flower   5      14   210 
A       car      2       6   90 
A       tree     7      16   240 
A       ball     1      11   165 
B       flower   5      14   266 
B       car      2      6    114 
B       tree     8      15   285 
B       ball     4      8    152 
C       flower   3      16   176 
C       car      2      6    66 
C       tree     1      22   242 
C       ball     5      7    77 
D       flower   6      13   221 
D       car      2      6    102 
D       tree     7      16   272 
D       ball     2      10   170
```

Comment: have a look at `tidyr::gather` to go from large to long

Comment: Thank you @HubertL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `dplyr` with `tidyr` as commented by @HubertL:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% 
       gather(Column, Count, -Category, -Total) %>% 
       mutate(Y = Total - Count) %>% 
       group_by(Column) %>% 
       mutate(X = Y * sum(Count))

#  Category Total Column Count  Y   X
#1   flower    19      A     5 14 210
#2      car     8      A     2  6  90
#3     tree    23      A     7 16 240
#4     ball    12      A     1 11 165
#5   flower    19      B     5 14 266
#6      car     8      B     2  6 114
# ...
```

Comment: Thank you @Psidom , what I don't get is that you are applying "gather" on  categories (e.g. "Column", "Count") that do not exist in the input data.frame

Comment: It's not applying on the two columns, but set the new columns names. You can check `gather` for more info, but basically here what it means is except for columns `Category` and `Total` which is what `-` is doing here, stack columns `A, B, C, D` to long format with `Column` as the name of columns that contains `ABCD` or key column, and `Count` as the name of the column that contains `5,2,7,1...` or value column. If this is still not clear, take a look at `df %>% gather(Column, Count, -Category, -Total)` and you will find out what it does.

Comment: Hi @Psidom, I have a problem with your solution, sum(Count) is computing the sum along the whole column, not for the grouped columns (A, B, etc.). Any idea about why this could happen?

Comment: Not exactly sure. Maybe detach and retach the `dplyr` package or restart R session. It shouldn't be an issue here normally.